# RestTemplateBuilder and RestTemplate and HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Following is a snippet of code to create RestTemplate bean:

```
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder)
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        factory.setXXX
        ...
        builder.requestFactory(() -> factory);             //*
        RestTemplate restTemplate = builder.build();
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);           //*
        return restTemplate;
    }
```

factory is passed twice: first to RestTemplateBuilder, then to restTemplate. Could anyone tell me why it's necessary given that RestTemplateBuilder builds the restTemplate?

Comment: You don't need it, there is one problem with your code though, the `builder.requestFactory` returns an new `RestTEmplateBuilder` which you should use, it doesn't modify the existing one. The code you have seems to be a workaround for that.

Comment: for builder.requestFactory(() -> factory), the documentation says: Set the Supplier of ClientHttpRequestFactory that should be called each time we build() a new RestTemplate instance.

for restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory), the documentation says: Set the request factory that this accessor uses for obtaining client request handles.

which one is not needed and why?

Comment: I already explained that including the error in your code. I fyou also look at the documentation you will see it `requestFactory` returns `RestTEmplateBuilder` which is a new instance, which you should use. As stated you aren't using that and hence in your sample code calling that method is useless.

Comment: Got it now. Would you give a little more details about the purpose of the other call which documentation says "Set the request factory that this accessor uses for obtaining client request handles"? how does request factory is used to "obtain client request handles"?